# Woocommerce product variations, Google product feed and nested loops in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-product-search

I'm trying to make a Google product feed from Woocommerce -  the available plugins to do this don't support product variations, which is a bit of a nuisance.

I'm working on a clothing shop with multiple sizes and colours of item, so it's required that the Google product feed should list all available size/colour combinations, and as it's doing stock control for each variation, there is no point listing the Size 10 White as in stock when all we really have left is Size 14 Brown.

So, I reckon what I need to do is create a product feed that runs a loop for each product, then inside that loop, runs a nested loop for each variation?  It's a bit slow, so please suggest a better way if there is one!   At least it will only have to run once a month.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 <?php
// First get the main product details.  
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

// Now do a second nested loop to get the variations. 
$args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'post_parent' =>'$id');
$variationloop = new WP_Query( $args2 );
while ( $variationloop->have_posts() ) : $variationloop->the_post();

// get the parent of each variation so we can use $parent (is this necessary???)
$parent = get_post($post->post_parent); 
?>
```

I feel that really having done the first loop, I should be able to call things from that, but once the second, variation loop is done, I don't seem to be able to refer to anything within the first, product loop.   Hence  get_post($post->post_parent)

And then I do the feed.  So far this seems to work:

```
    <item>
    <title><?php   echo $parent->post_title;?></title>
    <link>http://mysite.com/shop/<?php   echo $parent->post_name;?></link>
    <g:image_link><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ?></g:image_link>
    <g:price><?php echo $product->price ?></g:price>
    <g:condition>New</g:condition>
    <g:id><?php echo $id; ?></g:id>  
    <g:availability><?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? get_option('product_in_stock') : get_option('product_out_stock'); ?></g:availability>
    <g:brand>My Brandname</g:brand>
    <g:product_type>Clothing &amp; Accessories &gt;  Clothing &gt;  Swimwear</g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category>Clothing &amp; Accessories &gt;  Clothing &gt;  Swimwear</g:google_product_category>
    <g:shipping_weight><?php echo $product->get_weight();?></g:shipping_weight>

    <g:mpn><?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?></g:mpn>
    <?php if (get_option('rss_use_excerpt')) : ?>
    <description><![CDATA[<?php echo $parent->post_excerpt; ?>]]></description>
    <?php else : ?>
    <description><![CDATA[<?php echo $parent->post_excerpt; ?>]]></description>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Only this is incomplete -  I'm not sure how to get at all the elements that I need.  In particular, how do I retrieve the variation size and colour, which are in a different table?

Comment: Don't know about the issue, but I would take `$variationloop = new WP_Query( $args2 );` out of the first loop-while.

Comment: I need to show some values that are set at the variation level, and some that are set at the product level.

Comment: I misread that... try in the second query '`parent => $post->ID`

Comment: I'm already using 'post_parent' =>'$id' in the second loop?  It's in the $args2 array. 

 I originally nested the variationloop within the product loop because I was thinking that I needed to check if products were available, then get their variations if they were.  But if it's possible to check that a product has not been deleted from the variationloop, I could then only have one loop.  That would certainly speed things up! 

Any idea on how to get the associated size and colour for the variations?  I am confused by the tables wp_term, wp_term_relationships and wp_term_taxonomy.

Comment: The variable won't be parsed inside single quotes, anyway, it's only useful for `$var = "something-$id";`. If not, remove the quotes. But are you sure that `$id` contains something?

Comment: Oh yes, good point!  I should have been using $post->post_parent  - thanks!

I now have just one loop (hurray) and all the information that is stored per-product.  Unfortunately, I am still stuck on how Woocommerce links variation to properties like colour and size.  I can get the colours that belong to the product, but I'm stuck on how Woocommerce associates a colour with a variation. :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get this working, so am leaving details in case it's useful to anyone.

As per brasofilo's suggestion, I removed the second loop. Then I got the variations like this, checking with meta_compare to see that they were in stock.

```
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'post_count' =>'9999','meta_key' => '_stock',  'meta_value' => '0', 'meta_compare' => '>');
$variationloop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $variationloop->have_posts() ) : $variationloop->the_post();
// get the parent of each variation, so you can refer to things like product description that are set per-product not per-variation. 
$parent = get_post($post->post_parent); 
// is the parent product live? 
if ($parent->post_status=="publish")
{
```

Then I got the colours, sizes, photos etc like this:

```
 $colour= get_post_meta($id, 'attribute_pa_colour', true); 
 $size= get_post_meta($id, 'attribute_pa_size', true); 
 $price= get_post_meta($id, '_price', true); 
 $thephoto= get_post_meta($id, '_thumbnail_id', true);  // get photo associated with this variation
 $image_attributes =wp_get_attachment_image_src($thephoto, 'large');
```

Note that the exact name of the attributes will depend what you called that attribute when you set up your variations

Then I just echoed out the values:

post_title;?> -  Size 
http://mywebsite.com/shop/post_name;?>
ID; ?>


 

post_excerpt); ?>

 GBP

I hope that is helpful to someone!

Comment: ty ty ty :) this post gave me the info I needed to retrieve the value of my custom 'colour' attribute

I had been trying other WC functions with no success :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a great free plugin for woocommerce product feed which also support product variation. https://wordpress.org/plugins/webappick-product-feed-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

This premium plugin developed by ELEX supports even variations. Hope this helps those who are still looking for Google Product Feed integration for WooCommerce which supports Product Variations. 
https://elextensions.com/plugin/woocommerce-google-product-feed-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This free [woocommerce product feed plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) supports facebook product feed and google product feed including the product variations. Am answering this question as the OP searched for a plugin that supports variation for google product feed.